# How can I transfer etherbase status to another account within mist?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, jaxx

After importing a wallet from JAXX to Mist, I wish to have the JAXX account having Etherbase status, instead of the default Geth one. However, I see no visual indications on how to do this within Mist.. Can anyone offer an explanation?

Comment: Can anyone answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a console-based solution and an untested one, at that. If you run `geth attach` while Mist is running, you can probably connect to the running `geth` instance. Then, you can do the following:

```
eth.accounts; // list your accounts
miner.setEtherbase(yourdesiredetherbase) // Set your etherbase. Not sure if this does what you want or if it's persistent.
```